# Speeding up a For Loop with large number of Iterations ? Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, for-loop

I have the following simple For Loop in my Open GL ES app :

```
for (NSValue * value in pointerStorageArray) 
{
    NSLog(@"Freeing Malloced Data");

    free(value);
}
```

The problem is that the pointerStorageArray contains around 40000 data items (all the data for a 3D object) and therefore the loop takes about a minute to complete.

Is there any way I could speed up the time taken for the loop to complete ?

**EDIT**

This question is now an illustration of the importance of not coding for 18 hours in a row. Removing the NSLog Statement speeds it up from 5 minutes to 4 seconds ;)

Comment: I would expect it to go *much* faster without the `NSLog` function. Can you try it without that message?

Comment: Now runs in 5 seconds :)

Comment: Glad to hear it `:)` - it's a great illustration of *always profile your code before you start optimizing*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the slowdown is actually caused by repeated calls to `free()`, then you could consider allocating a few larger contiguous blocks of memory, rather than 40000 individual ones.

As always, you should find a way to profile your code to determine exactly where the bottleneck is.

Comment: It's the calls to free that are bottlenecking. My C knowledge is not very good. The issue is that the a malloc statement is being called from a for loop and assigning, as you say, 40 000 individual blocks of memory. Could you point me in the right direction on how to merge them ?

Comment: Ideally you'd allocate everything out of a separate pool and then just toss the pool.  I've never done that on iOS, though, so I don't know precisely how you'd do it.